# Satmar Rebbe's opinion on Mechitza

Tags: sources-mekorot, shiurim-measurements, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, mechitza-partition, satmar

Where could I find the opinion of [the Satmar Rebbe (Rav Yoel) zt'l](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Teitelbaum) on the height and laws pertaining to the Mechitzah?

Comment: http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5762/vayigash.html

Comment: What specific Sefer of the Divrei Yoel? שאלות ותשובות?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I linked in the comments it can be found in Divrei Yoel 1:10.
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20289&st=&pgnum=78&hilite=